# Auto tagging in AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-glue, terraform-provider-aws, tagging

I am trying to create auto tagging for glue in AWS but I am not sure if my code is right.  There is already a Lambda function to invoke the auto tagging of other services but I am trying to add the events that need to be tagged. I have a couple of questions pertaining to this.

1. What are the events that I can tag for Glue.
2. What am I supposed to check while testing this code and if it's working?

```
import boto3

import aws_tagging
glue_client = boto3.client('glue')

def tags_list_to_dict(tags):
    ''' convert list of single 'Key':'Value' dictionaries to single dict '''
    result = {}
    for tag in tags:
        if 'key' in tag:
            result[tag['key']] = tag['value']
        elif 'Key' in tag:
            result[tag['Key']] = tag['Value']
        elif 'tagKey' in tag:
            result[tag['tagKey']] = tag['tagValue']
        else:
            print(f"item: {tag.keys()} does not contain a supported schema, ignoring item")
    return result


def get_requester_tags(event):
    ''' get tags from requesting iam entity '''
    print(f"requester type: {event['detail']['userIdentity']['type']}")

    if event['detail']['userIdentity']['type'] == "IAMUser":

        user_name = event['detail']['userIdentity']['userName']
        tags = tags_list_to_dict(iam_client.list_user_tags(UserName=user_name)['Tags'])
    elif event['detail']['userIdentity']['type'] == "IAMRole":

        role_name = event['detail']['userIdentity']['RoleName']
        tags = tags_list_to_dict(iam_client.list_role_tags(RoleName=role_name)['Tags'])
    elif event['detail']['userIdentity']['type'] == 'AssumedRole':

        user_name = event['detail']['userIdentity']['sessionContext']['sessionIssuer']['userName']
        tags = tags_list_to_dict(iam_client.list_role_tags(RoleName=user_name)['Tags'])
    else:
        tags = None

    return tags


def get_secret_info(name):
    response = secretsmanager_client.list_secrets(
        Filters=[
            {'Key': 'name', 'Values': [name]}
        ],
        SortOrder='asc'
    )
    return response['SecretList'][0]['Tags']


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ''' main handler '''

    mandatory_tags = ['XYZ', 'ABC', 'PQR']
    default_value = "UNKNOWN"
    requester_tags = get_requester_tags(event)

    if requester_tags is None:
        print(f"invalid event or user identity")
        return

    for tag in mandatory_tags:
        if tag in requester_tags:
            pass
        else:
            requester_tags[tag] = default_value
    print(event)
    print(f"requester tags: {requester_tags}")
    print(f"source: {event['detail']['eventSource']}, event name: {event['detail']['eventName']}")

    elif event['source'] == "aws.glue":
        try:
            resource_tags = tags_list_to_dict(event['detail']['requestParameters']['tags'])
        except:
            resource_tags = []

        if event['detail']['eventName'] == "CreateBlueprint":
            arn = event['details']['responseElements']['blueprintArn']
            list_of_tags = []
            for tag in mandatory_tags:
                if tag not in resource_tags:
                    aws_tagging.tag_glue_resource(glue_client, arn, tag, requester_tags[tag])

        elif event['detail']['eventName'] == "CreateDataQualityRuleset":
            name = event['detail']['responseElements']['dataQualityRuleset']['name']
            arn = f"arn:aws:glue:{event['account']}:{event['region']}:dataquality-ruleset/{name}"
            for tag in mandatory_tags:
                if tag not in resource_tags:
                    aws_tagging.tag_glue_resource(glue_client, arn, tag, requester_tags[tag])

    else:
        print("No events matched in Glue")
    else:
        print("No events matched")
```

I am trying to auto tag a couple of glue events when they are triggered. I am not sure how to test this.